# Why is my ceiling protruding here, is it safe to drill?

Tags: ceiling, mounting

I want to screw this 3.5 inch screw into my ceiling in the red area.
My stud finder indicates the red area is a stud / joist.

I'm not sure why the ceiling is protruding here, should I avoid this area ? and drill in the yellow area instead ? How can I know if this stud is wood or concrete / rebarb ?

Update:

There is a 2 inch width, 8 inch high wooden beam at the red spot. What type of screw should I use for a 25 pound weight if I use 2 screws.

[image: drill location ceiling]

[image: drill screw]

Comment: There is a air duct hidden behind it

Comment: Does that mean it's safe to mount anything in the red area  ?

Comment: well, it is a trick question, you could drill right next to it or in it

Comment: It is a chase/duct for HVAC covered with drywall/wood.  The real question is how much weight you plan on hanging there, since it probably does not have much more weight bearing than the drywall.

Comment: 3.5" screws are very chancy if you don't know what's actually there, as they will be longer than the depth that plumbing and wiring can be placed without additional protection (steel plates to advise the would be hole driller to try a different spot, though some just get determined and drill through them anyway, leading to sparks or leaks unless they get lucky...) You need an investagotory hole and a borescope, or an acceptace of drywall repair and painting and a bigger hole you can look through.

Comment: If this is an apartment with maintenance people, have a conversation with one of them about the ceiling system and what level of load can be suspended from it. If the system is anchored to a concrete flat slab, for instance, then it might have very little capacity. It looks like you might be hanging something heavy.

Comment: I found there is a 2 inch width wooden beam exactly in the corner ( approximately 8 inches high ). Is it safe to attach a 25 pound object to it ?

Comment: @Willem, even if it was only a 2x2, I would be comfortable with it. You can always imagine a scenario where some quirk causes a problem. I guess the price of whatever you're hanging could persuade me to investigate further, but for something like a television I would install it and not give it a second thought.